# Windows 7 AltTab tweaking

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

Is there a way to increase the size of thumb images on classic Windows 7 alt-tab. I am not looking for a replacement tool.

Comment: Is Flip 3d not an option?  I'm finding it to be more useful than the traditional alt-tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I used [this tutorial](http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-bigger-thumbnails-for-vistas-alt-tab/) to do this and it works fine.